# error C2296: '%' : illegal, left operand has type 'double' in C++

Tags: c++, double

I have to use '%' with double numbers, but in C++ it doesn't work.
Example:

```
double x;
temp = x%10;
```

I get this error:

```
error C2296: '%' : illegal, left operand has type 'double'
```

How can I solve this problem without converting the number from double to integer?
If I converted it, I will lose the fractional part, and I don't want.

Is there another alternative?

Comment: `%` operator is not defined for `double`s. You can do `int % anotherInt`. Try [`fmod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod)

Comment: What result to you expect by applying % to double?

Comment: Division with remainders only makes sense for integer division. `53.0/10 == 5.3` so there's no remainder for `double` division.

Comment: @MSalters There is no inherent problem defining % for doubles - if there were, Java could not do it, and C++ `fmod` would be impossible to define. Whether % can be applied to doubles is simply a language design choice.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: It can be defined, but it works _very_ differently from integer modulo.  To avoid confusing people, C++ didn't define it, to make it harder to accidentally select the wrong one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`%` is not defined for doubles, but you can use `fmod` instead:

> Compute remainder of division
>   Returns the floating-point remainder of numer/denom (rounded towards zero):

Example (adapted for C++) from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/:

```
#include <cmath>       /* fmod */
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
  std::cout << "fmod of 5.3 / 2 is " <<  std::fmod (5.3, 2) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've got the similar trouble but your suggestion doesn't work for mine. It's because the trouble occurring at >C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winbase.h(1999): It's Microsoft file. It's not feasible to update it. Any way to conquer this trouble other than this way?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `fmod` function

```
#include <math.h>

double x;
temp = fmod(x, 10.0);
```

Comment: `#include <cmath>`, probably, as this is C++, and `std::fmod`.