# I have been created a template function but i got an error for checking if the input is an odd or even in C++

Tags: c++, function, templates, if-statement, parameters

I have been created the template function to check for the minimum between three different data types which are ( int , float , and char ) I think my code is pretty much good but when it come to executing it said `invalid operands of types 'float' and 'int' to binary operator %` I'm not sure what to do in this case, my code is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

template <class type>

    type mini(type a , type b)
    {
        type x;
        x = fmod(a,b);
        if (x ==0)
        {
            cout<<"it is an even";
            return x;
        }
        else
            cout<<"it is an odd";
            return x;
    }

int main()
{
    cout<<"Enter an integer:";
    int a,b;
    cin>>a>>b;
    mini <int> (a,b);
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"Enter a character:";
    char x,y;
    cin>>x>>y;
    mini <char> (x,y);
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"Enter a floating pointing:";
    float c,d;
    cin>>c>>d;
    mini <float> (c,d);
    cout<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I updated the code, is it correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with fmod as the double don't have the operator % implemented.

Below link can help more:
[error C2296: '%' : illegal, left operand has type 'double' in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237232/error-c2296-illegal-left-operand-has-type-double-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

The modulus (%) operator does not work with `double` or `float`.

You can create a specialization of the function and use `fmod()`/`fmodf()` instead.
Beware of comparing floating point numbers with `0` though.

```
template<>
float mini(float a, float b)
...
```

Comment: but i'm testing my program with ("float , int , and char ")

Comment: i edit it but still not working for the template function to check whether is odd or even

Comment: i edit it but still not working for the template function to check whether is odd or even

Answer (score 1):

Doing this with floating points is a bit tricky since there's no guarantee that the remainder of a division with 2 will result in exactly 0 even for entered numbers that are clearly even. Also, the numbers you enter may not be stored exactly as you entered them, which can also change the odd/even characteristic. [Epsilon](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon) can help in some cases, but it'll just settle for `>` 0 here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <type_traits>
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

// the function template for integer types
template <class type, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<type>, int> = 0>
type mini(type a, type b)
{
    auto min = std::min(a, b);
    if(min%2) std::cout << "The int " << min << " is odd\n";
    else std::cout << "The int " << min << " is even\n";
    return min;
}

// the function template for floating point types
template<class type, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<type>, int> = 0>
type mini(type a, type b) {
    auto min = std::min(a, b);

    // do the floating point modulus operation
    auto mod = std::abs(std::fmod(min, type{2}));

    // check if it's bigger than a default initialized "type" (0.f or 0.)
    if(mod > type{}) // std::numeric_limits<type>::epsilon())
        std::cout << "The float " << min << " is odd\n";
    else
        std::cout << "The float " << min << " is even\n";
    return min;
}

// the rest is just for testing

std::istringstream cin(
    "5 4\n"
    "a b\n"
    "6.1 4.0000002\n"             // float  - even, stored as 4
    "6.1 4.0000001\n"             // double - odd, has enough precision
    "6666666653 6666666653\n"     // float  - looks odd, right? Probably not...
);

template<typename type>
void enter(const char* txt) {
    type a, b;
    std::cout << "Enter two " << txt << ':';
    if(cin >> a >> b)
        mini(a, b);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::setprecision(20);
    enter<int>("ints");
    enter<char>("chars");
    enter<float>("floats");
    enter<double>("doubles");
    enter<float>("floats again");
}
```

Possible output:

```
Enter two ints:The int 4 is even
Enter two chars:The int a is odd
Enter two floats:The float 4 is even
Enter two doubles:The float 4.0000001000000002804 is odd
Enter two floats again:The float 6666666496 is even
```